# Relation between PC bus and physical device slot

Tags: linux, operating-systems, pci

I'm trying to understand how a pc bus works. Here are my questions:

1. How is a bus related to a physical onboard device slot. Please give some examples.
2. Is it true that many device slots share the same PCI bus?
3. "Each bus can host up to 32 devices" - does it mean that up to 32 devices could be connected to one PCI bus?
4. Is the device number field from `lspci` command just a physical slot number (like 1 for PCI1 onboard slot)?

Comment: Physical slots are completely motherboard-specific and not guaranteed to have any correlation with the device numbers listed by `lspci`.

Answer (score 0):

- How is a bus related to a physical on-board device slot. Please give some examples.

One slot is usually mapped to one slot on the bus but without any kind of documentation you won't be able to tell which slot of which bus or even how many buses are available. A [bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)) is actually concept.

- Is it true that many device slots share the same PCI bus?

Yes. If you think about PCI you might have a printer card, a sound card and some other low bandwidth thing on it so it made sense to make those components share a single bus as they wouldn't hinder each other.

- "Each bus can host up to 32 devices" - does it mean that up to 32 devices could be connected to one PCI bus?

Yes. Depending on the bus this might include the controller itself. If I'm not mistaken that's how SCSI works.